# CodeIgniter - Generate routes dynamically

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a website with a dynamic navigational menu. I keep the controller (portuguese) names in a database, together with the translation to english.

I want to know if it is possible to affect the 'route' array at runtime, so it would create those routes and cache it when the page is loaded.

I hope I was clear enough, thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

Create a table named Routes

```
--
-- Table structure for table `Routes`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Routes` (
`idRoutes` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Order` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Url` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`Url_Variable` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`Class` text NOT NULL,
`Method` text NOT NULL,
`Variable` text NOT NULL,
`Date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (`idRoutes`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=67 ;
```

Create a file in the config directory named pdo_db_connect.php

Put this inside and change accordingly.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

function pdo_connect(){

try{

    // Include database info
    include 'database.php';

if(!isset($db)){
    echo 'Database connection not available!';
        exit;
}   
        $dbdriver   = $db['default']['dbdriver'];//'mysql'; 
        $hostname   = $db['default']['hostname'];//'localhost';
        $database   = $db['default']['database'];//'config';
        $username   = $db['default']['username'];//'root';
        $password   = $db['default']['password'];//'password';

    //to connect
    $DB = new PDO($dbdriver.':host='.$hostname.'; dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
    return $DB;

}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Please contact Admin: '.$e->getMessage();
}

}
```

Now in your routes file you can do this:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    // Include our PDO Connection
    include('application/config/pdo_db_connect.php');

    class dynamic_route{

        public $pdo_db = FALSE;

        public function __construct(){

        }
        private function query_routes(){
            try{

            $routes_query = $this->pdo_db->query('SELECT * FROM Routes ORDER BY `Order` ASC');

            if($routes_query){
                $return_data = array(); 
                foreach($routes_query as $row) {
                    $return_data[] = $row; 
                }
                return $return_data;

            }

            }catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo 'Please contact Admin: '.$e->getMessage();
            }

        }
        private function filter_route_data($data){

            $r_data = array();
            foreach($data as $row){
                $return_data = new stdClass;

                if(empty($row['Url_Variable']) ){
                    $return_data->url = $row['Url'];
                }else{
                    $return_data->url = $row['Url'].'/'.$row['Url_Variable'];
                }

                if(empty($row['Method']) && empty($row['Variable']) ){
                    $return_data->route = $row['Class'];

                }elseif(!empty($row['Method']) && empty($row['Variable']) ){
                    $return_data->route = $row['Class'].'/'.$row['Method'];
                }elseif(!empty($row['Method']) && !empty($row['Variable']) ){
                    $return_data->route = $row['Class'].'/'.$row['Method'].'/'.$row['Variable'];
                }

            $r_data[] = $return_data;
            }
            return $r_data;
        }
        public function get_routes(){
            $route_data = $this->query_routes();
            $return_data = $this->filter_route_data($route_data);
            return $return_data;
        }       

    }

    $dynamic_route = new dynamic_route;
    // Give dynamic route database connection
    $dynamic_route->pdo_db = pdo_connect();
    // Get the route data
    $route_data = $dynamic_route->get_routes();
    //Iterate over the routes
    foreach($route_data as $row){
        $route[$row->url] = $row->route;
    }
```

Comment: Kyle, i have no way to test this as i'm not even working with PHP anymore for a long time now. Have you tested this? If you tell me you're sure this code works i will accept your answer as it seems to do exactly what i asked for

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can take a look here:

- http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/185154/
- http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/182180/

Comment: Thank you for the first link. It's enlightening!

Answer (score 3):

Remember that the routes file is just a PHP file that contains an array, so if you want to get your "Hacker" t-shirt on you could easily do something a little bit dirty.

Have your CMS/application/web-app/fridge-monitoring-system/whatever to have an interface which creates and stores records in a database. Then whenever you save, throw this content into application/cache/routes.php.

Lastly you just have your main routes.php include the cached version and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You need the following.

One controller like this which will save your routes to a file called "routes.php" in the application/cache folder:

```
public function save_routes()
        {

            // this simply returns all the pages from my database
            $routes = $this->Pages_model->get_all($this->siteid);

            // write out the PHP array to the file with help from the file helper
            if (!empty($routes)) {
                // for every page in the database, get the route using the recursive function - _get_route()
                foreach ($routes->result_array() as $route) {
                    $data[] = '$route["' . $this->_get_route($route['pageid']) . '"] = "' . "pages/index/{$route['pageid']}" . '";';
                }

                $output = "<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');\n";

                $output .= implode("\n", $data);

                $this->load->helper('file');
                write_file(APPPATH . "cache/routes.php", $output);
            }
        }
```

Here's the second function you will need. This one and the one prior will both go in your application controller which handles your pages:

```
// Credit to http://acairns.co.uk for this simple function he shared with me
// this will return our route based on the 'url' field of the database
// it will also check for parent pages for hierarchical urls
        private function _get_route($id)
        {
            // get the page from the db using it's id
            $page = $this->Pages_model->get_page($id);

            // if this page has a parent, prefix it with the URL of the parent -- RECURSIVE
            if ($page["parentid"] != 0)
                $prefix = $this->_get_route($page["parentid"]) . "/" . $page['page_name'];
            else
                $prefix = $page['page_name'];

            return $prefix;
        }
```

In your Pages_model you will need something along this line:

```
function get_page($pageid) {
        $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('pages')
            ->where('pageid', $pageid);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        $row = $query->row_array();
        $num = $query->num_rows();

        if ($num < 1)
        {
            return NULL;

        } else {
            return $row;
        }
    }
```

And this:

```
function get_all($siteid) {
        $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('pages')
            ->where('siteid', $siteid)
            ->order_by('rank');
        ;

        $query = $this->db->get();

        $row = $query->row_array();
        $num = $query->num_rows();

        if ($num < 1)
        {
            return NULL;

        } else {
            return $query;
        }
    }
```

Every time a page is created, you'll need to have this line executed so I suggest putting it at the end of the controller after all the dirty work is done:

```
$this->save_routes();
```

All this together will make you a sweet routes file that will be constantly updated whenever things change.

Answer (score 1):

Something not overly complex, and it keeps the URLs friendly:

inside of routes.php:

```
// Routes from the database
require_once (BASEPATH .'database/DB.php');
$db =& DB();

// slug will be something like
// 'this-is-a-post'
// 'this-is-another-post'
$sql = "SELECT id, slug FROM items";
$query = $db->query($sql);

$result = $query->result();
foreach( $result as $row )
{
    // first is if multiple pages
    $route["$row->slug/(:num)"] = "item/index/$row->id";
    $route["$row->slug"] = "item/index/$row->id";
}
```

This assumes 'id' as a primary key and that 'slug' will be unique

Inside your controller, you can obtain the id by:

```
    $id = $this->uri->rsegment(3);
```